# How were "Heat distortion" effects done in older shows?

Tags: anime-production

A lot of shows from the 90s/early 2000s used a wibbling effect to mimic heat distortion.
An example can be seen in several Slayers episodes:
[image]

considering they are still images with a frame rate of less than 30 FPS, I am wondering how this effect was achieved with such fluidity.

Comment: By filming through moving water, presumanly